# В чем отличия /dev/full от /dev/zero?

Tags: android, linux, alsa, chroot

Мне необходимо в Linux chroot на Android смартфоне использовать команду alsa arecord. Но я получаю ошибку об отсутствии /dev/full. Могу ли я заменить это устройство симлинкой на /dev/zero?
Спасибо.

Comment: [X-Y](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy)

Comment: `/dev/null` может?

Answer (score 2):

null создаётся командой

```
mknod /dev/null  c 1 3
```

zero от null отличается тем, что zero - это выход нулей бесконечной длины, а null - это только вход. В zero, так же как и в null, можно записывать без ограничений.

Можно использовать zero для скрытия ненужных данных таким же образом, как и с null.

Но /dev/full создаётся

```
mknod -m 666 /dev/full c 1 7
```

И поведение у него на запись противоположно zero и null.

Comment: Спасибо, но Вы не очень внимательно прочитали, не /dev/null, а /dev/full.

Comment: @PavelSamsonov /dev/full - это устройство, переполненное данными. При записи в /dev/full происходит ошибка. Но это все равно не должно работать на Android даже в принципе, как и ALSA

Comment: @PavelSamsonov дополнил